# Where can I get Hibernate Shards Jars/ maven dependency entry in xml

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to implement hibernate shards sample java application using Maven. I am not able to find jars.

Below is the pom.xml entry. But, am always getting this error --> "Missing artifact hibernate:shards:jar:3.0.0B2" Please help me how to get it resolved.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>shards</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0B2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate Shards is not currently available in the online Maven repository.

You can find the Shards distributables here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-shards/3.0.0.Beta2/

You can manually install the Hibernate Shards jar in your local repo following these instructions: http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=62144

However this will have the disadvantage that your build is not easily reproducable on another machine. A better thing to do would be to look into hosting your own maven repository (e.g. using Sonatype Nexus) and deploy Hibernate Shards there.

Comment: Yes.. I have gone through that thread as well. May I know from where can I download the jar? In order to install that in local m2 repo we need to download it to some folder and run that command.

Comment: Oops, sorry didn't see your comment! Please see my last edit.